# What's this CGContextRestoreGState Error when I try to draw into a UITableView cell in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, renderer

How do I prevent this error, please?

: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

```
import UIKit
import MGSwipeTableCell

class CustomCellRenderer: MGSwipeTableCell {

    //total range #f30649 --- #eaa026
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        var currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);
        var colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        var startColor = UIColor( netHex:0xf30649 )
        var startColorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(startColor.CGColor)
        var endColor =  UIColor( netHex:0xdc9422 )
        var endColorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(endColor.CGColor)
        var colorComponents
        = [startColorComponents[0], startColorComponents[1], startColorComponents[2], startColorComponents[3], endColorComponents[0], endColorComponents[1], endColorComponents[2], endColorComponents[3]]
        var locations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
        var gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace,&colorComponents,&locations,2)
        var startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        var endPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext,gradient,startPoint,endPoint, 0)
        CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with the: `CGContextSaveGState` / `CGContextRestoreGState` calls. I don't know what but I'd start looking there.

Comment: I realized just removing that method seems to work fine.